# How do I add a new controller in front of a nested controller so that users don't have to issue two requests to API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have created a Rails 5 API with two controllers, one nested within the other one, such that in order to create a new Deployment, you have to create a Template first, and get it's ID. i.e. POST /templates//deployments. I did this this way because a Template is a static object that should never change over many months, but a deployment is a changing thing that is potentially new every time.  A deployment is something you do with a template, therefore you shouldn't be able to create a deployment unless a template already exists.

I spoke with the developers who will use this service, and they complained about having to use two requests to make a Deployment. I argued for my design, but I failed to convince them.  I am a junior in the organization, and I don't have the power to make them do what I want.

Therefore, I need to create a third controller, called QuickDeployment, that accepts a params hash containing params for both the template and the deployment.  If the template already exists, it should use it, otherwise it should create an new one.  It should create a new deployment regardless.  A deployment is an object with a state machine and workflow - users should be able to get the current state of the deployment with a GET /quick_deployments/.

I'm wondering if that third controller needs to have a model which would have references to the template and deployment is created, or not?  I want to avoid if I can repeating myself with respect to the parameters and behaviors of the templates and deployments associated with the QuickDeployment.

So do I create a QuickDeployment model, or not?  Can I accomplish the same thing without creating the model, using routing or something?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if that third controller needs to have a model which
>   would have references to the template and deployment is created, or
>   not?

No. Your new controller would basically extract your template parameters from the POST request, create the template record, then create a deployment record which belongs to the newly created template with the deployment parameters.